# How to actually name this kind of "inheritance"?

Tags: class, inheritance, kotlin, instance

I was teached that when you create an inheritance, then you inherit an object **definition** as a parent.

In Kotlin I can run this code:

```
fun main(args : Array<String>) {
    open class aux (val input : Int) {
        fun print() {
            System.out.println(this.input)
        }
    }

    class baz : aux(5)
    class bar : aux(6)

    val x = baz()
    x.print()       // 5

    val y = bar()
    y.print()       // 6
}
```

In this case I can't really tell that baz (or bar) inherits from aux, because there are different implementations for inherited class, one takes 5 inside constructor, another one takes 6. That makes them possible to work totally different.

I don't know how to name what this code do, because for me inheriting an instance is far away from what I saw as a programmer.

I can't think of any case where this code would help to  make better software, sure it's sweet, but it's also very hard to debug

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand your point. It's not Kotlin-specific, you can do the very same in Java:

```
class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Aux bar = new Bar();
    Aux baz = new Baz();
    System.out.println(bar.getValue());
    System.out.println(baz.getValue());
  }
}

class Aux {
    private int value;
    public Aux(int i) {
        value = i;
    }

    public int getValue() {
      return value;
    }
}

class Baz extends Aux {
    public Baz() {
        super(4);
    }
}

class Bar extends Aux {
    public Bar() {
        super(5);
    }
}
```

That prints:

```
5
4
```

To make a more concrete example, you can have a base class `Vehicle`, accepting an int as constructor arguments (e.g., the number of wheels), and you can have child classes not requiring that value (e.g., a `Car extends Vehicle` which always has 4 wheels). You can think of it as "giving a meaningful value" in case that's reasonable for your domain. Of course, you can take that value from the caller, if you wish so:

```
class Baz extends Aux { 
    public Baz(int value) {
        super(value);
    }
}
```

The general idea is that you need to provide all the data that you need to build the parent object from the child constructor. After that, you need to finish constructing the child object, but if that object doesn't need/accept any additional data, then you don't need other arguments.

Comment: It makes more sense now, but the syntax of this in Kotlin is weird. It enforces me to understand how this works under the hood, or be more suspecting while debugging. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Glad to be helpful. Kotlin has been designed to be concise, so initially you might get tricked by that. Naming classes with capital letters might help you in recognizing an object creation